# How to prevent "How do you want to open this file" dialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, windows-shell

In my app I open a report using HTML file as such:

```
//pStrPath is file:///C:/Users/appts/AppData/Local/Temp/Report_View.htm
ShellExecute(hParentWnd, L"", pStrPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

On my development machine it opens up in a web browser, but when I just tested it on a new installation of Windows 10, it showed this dialog instead:

[image]

So how can I prevent it from being shown and go with "keep using this app" option from the get-go? Otherwise it may be very confusing for my users.

PS. Note that Edge is installed and can open `.htm` files if I double-click them.

Comment: Have you tried opening the browser directly with the url as a parameter for the browser?

Comment: Have you tried passing a verb to `ShellExecute`? I.e "open", "print" etc, etc. From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx#verbs it seems that using the 'open' verb would do the trick.

Comment: @enhzflep: I can't repro it. It's not showing that window anymore. I will have to reset Windows 10 to repro it, I guess. Very annoying...

Comment: @c00000fd - Bother! What a nuisance. Inconsistency - one aspect of human behaviour we'd prefer computers didn't emulate...

Comment: You should be passing `NULL` instead of `L""` as the verb.  When `NULL` is used, the file's default action is invoked, whatever it happens to be. Also, you should be using `ShellExecuteEx()` instead, as it provides more accurate error reporting.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks. Can't test it now. Need to reinstall Win10.... and that sucker doesn't install fast :)

Comment: @enhzflep: yes, adding `L"open"` instead of `L""` gets rid of that dialog. Do you want to make it into an answer and I'll mark it? As for using `NULL` it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @c00000fd - bewdy! Done. :)

Comment: @c00000fd `"open"` is not the default verb for all file types, and not all types even have a `"open"` verb. As for `NULL`, the documentation says: "*The default verb is used, if available. If not, the "open" verb is used. If neither verb is available, the system uses the first verb listed in the registry.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [Launching Applications (ShellExecute, ShellExecuteEx, SHELLEXECUTEINFO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx#verbs) we note the text

---

**Object Verbs**

The verbs available for an object are essentially the items that you find on an object's shortcut menu. To find which verbs are available, look in the registry under **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**\**CLSID**{object_clsid}\**Shell**\verb

Commonly available verbs include:

- **edit**  - Launches an editor and opens the document for editing.
- **find**  - Initiates a search starting from the specified directory.
- **open**  - Launches an application. If this file is not an executable
  file, its associated application is launched.
- **print** - Prints the document file.
- **properties** - Displays the object's properties.

---

Given that a double-click is <strike>the</strike> generally equivalent to selecting "open" in the object's shortcut menu, if we supply the function with the **open** verb, we can expect the behaviour to mirror that of a user's double-click. - *Please see Ken's comment below*

As such, we can expect the following code to achieve the desired result.

```
//pStrPath is file:///C:/Users/appts/AppData/Local/Temp/Report_View.htm
ShellExecute(hParentWnd, L"open", pStrPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: A double-click is not necessarily the equivalent of *open*. Double-clicking a .PDF with a recent version of Acrobat Reader, for instance, defaults to *Open with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC*, which will not respond to *open* when used with ShellExecute. If you're looking for the default action, it's best to leave the action empty ("").

Comment: @KenWhite - thank-you for the clarification Ken. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Ken Pass NULL for default verb

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: if I pass `NULL` it will still show that dialog. So far passing `"open"` seems to solve it. I just tested it on Windows 10.

Comment: My point is that you pass NULL to get the default verb. That's stated in the documentation. My comment was not speaking directly to the question but instead to Ken's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open the default program FROM a 32 bit program in 64 bit Windows the ShellExecute and ShellExecuteEX may display the "How do you want to open this file?" dialog box each time.  This is due to the way that the default program registered itself in Windows I think.

I could reproduce this error on Windows 11 fresh install where the Photos is set to the Default Program for .jpg files.

In my case, I found that if I use the ShellExecuteExW function and pass the extension into the .lpClass of SHELLEXECUTEINFOW Type that it works.
It should  also work with the ShellExecuteExA function

1. Make sure it's not an exe, reg, bat file, or a URL you are trying to open.  It has to be a document type of file.
2. Use the .lpClass to pass the extension like ".jpg"
3. Add the SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME As Long = &H1 to the .fMask parameter you are passing in like .fMask = YourMaskValue Or SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME

The reason I think this works is it bypasses any redirection and reads directly from the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.jpg